# C# Web App - Toolbar not showing, on IPAD, when displaying PDFs

Tags: c#, .net, ipad

Our web app displays PDFs to our internal users.  When they use an IPAD the toolbar doesn't show which makes it so they can't see anything but the first page.  They also can't print or download. I'm hoping that someone knows how to resolve this issue. We are displaying drawings that are stored in a database and building the pdf programmatically.  We use an ajax call to call the CreatePDF method.

```
    public string CreatePDF(string drawingNum, string rev, Byte[] bytes, bool isCurrentRev)
    {
        string unc = $"/repository/{drawingNum}__rev{rev}.pdf";
        string absolutePath = null;

        try
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(unc), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            absolutePath = fs.Name;
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.IndexOf("being used by another") == -1)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        if (!isCurrentRev)
        {
            //Add Watermark if not Current Revision
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            doc.LoadFromFile(absolutePath);

            for (int p = 0; p < doc.Pages.Count; p++)
            {
                PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages[p];
                PdfTilingBrush brush = new PdfTilingBrush(new SizeF(page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height / (float)2.75));
                brush.Graphics.SetTransparency(0.3f);
                brush.Graphics.Save();
                brush.Graphics.TranslateTransform(brush.Size.Width / 2, brush.Size.Height / 2);
                brush.Graphics.RotateTransform(45);
                brush.Graphics.DrawString("Obsolete", new PdfFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 70), PdfBrushes.Red, 0, 0, new PdfStringFormat(PdfTextAlignment.Center));
                brush.Graphics.Restore();
                brush.Graphics.SetTransparency(1);
                page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(brush, new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 0), page.Canvas.ClientSize));
            }
            doc.SaveToFile(absolutePath);
        }

        return unc;
    }
```

Then we display it in an iframe.

```
        success: function (data) {
            curDraw = data;
            $('#z-pdfIframe')[0].outerHTML = '<iframe id="z-pdfIframe" src="' + data.unc + '#zoom=Fit' + '" class="pdf" onload="iframeLoaded()"></iframe>';
            if (frm != 4) {
                DrawingDetailsContainer(data.detailsContainer);
            }
```